# Is there a native way to redirect a user to a page including a status code within an event observer?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, url-rewrite, redirect, header

I need to redirect a user to another page with a status code of 503 within an event observer. While I am able to redirect the user with `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('/foo/bar/')`, this doesn't appear to take an argument for a status code. Using `header()` doesn't work either, presumably because it's called too late in the process.

I've been scratching my head for ages, so I might be looking over something incredibly obvious. Any pointers would be appreciated, however. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your requirements cannot be met. Redirection is done through status code 301 or 302, so you cannot send two status codes. What you /can/ do, is make sure the target URL always generates a 503 response.

Comment: How would I go about properly doing this? Through .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll cumulate the information from the comments into one answer:

What you technically try to do is not possible, because it does not make sense. A redirection is defined by 3xx status codes, and one response cannot have multiple status codes.

What you actually want to do is sending a 503 status code on the target `/foo/bar` itself. So use this in your `Foo_BarController` action:

$this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(503);

If you don't want to send 503 all the time for this page, you could still use a URL parameter in the redirect and check it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(503);
```

Comment: The response code remains 301/302.

Comment: Be glad, otherwise you wouldn't have the redirect. The code above is meant to be executed on the target page.